# Photo browsing and viewing application

Tags: macos, photos

Can anyone recommend a good photo browsing application.

I have hundreds of photos in well organized folders categorized by year and location where they were taken on my mac but I want a way to actually look at them that fast and simple.

Any ideas?  I am happy to buy an app from the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) from Google for that.

It is not intrusive (will leave your photos in place), and it will not make duplicates (saves space on your disk).

It also comes with Google web space (so you can upload/download) and easy share with others.

Here is what they say about them self:

> - Picasa does not store the photos on your computer.
>
> When you open Picasa, it simply looks at the folders on your computer
>   and displays the photos it finds. It displays the file types that you
>   tell it to find, in the folders that you tell it to search.
>
> - Your original photos are always preserved.
>
> When using editing tools in Picasa, your original files are never
>   touched. The photo edits you make are only viewable in Picasa until
>   you decide to save your changes. Even then, Picasa creates a new
>   version of the photo with your edits applied, leaving the original
>   file totally preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just wait for the new Photos.app within MAC OS 10.10 coming in the Fall.
If you need to do something right now, Picasa is an option.

Though, you may want to just import them all into iPhoto, you can disable iPhoto from making copies of the photos on import (in preferences) and instead just reference the photos where they are currently while still having them to view in iPhoto.

There are other options of course, but they require paid software which might be unnecessary.